# Run PostgreSQL streaming replication synchronous and asynchronous simultaneously

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, streaming, replication, synchronous

I am using PostgreSQL 14 and ubuntu as my OS.

- I have done the database replication in synchronous mode
- Now I want to add another server and the **relationship between primary and new_standby** node will be **asynchronous**.
- Another problem, how to set application_name for different nodes? I have got same **application_name=14/main** for my two standby servers

Can anyone help me to solve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run it simultaneously.

You should have this configuration in your primary node:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 16
wal_keep_segments = 32
synchronous_commit = on
synchronous_standby_names = 'pgsql_0_node_0'
```

Restart the node to take the changes:

```
$ systemctl restart postgresql-14
```

Create the replication role:

```
$ CREATE ROLE replication_user WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'PASSWORD' REPLICATION;
```

And configure this in your standby nodes:

Both:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
hot_standby = on
```

Sync:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
promote_trigger_file='/tmp/failover_5432.trigger'
recovery_target_timeline=latest
primary_conninfo='application_name=pgsql_0_node_0 host=PRIMARY_NODE port=5432 user=replication_user password=PASSWORD'
```

***Replace PRIMARY_NODE, user, and password with the correct values.***

Async:

```
promote_trigger_file='/tmp/failover_5432.trigger'
recovery_target_timeline=latest
primary_conninfo='application_name=pgsql_0_node_1 host=PRIMARY_NODE port=5432 user=replication_user password=PASSWORD'
```

***Replace PRIMARY_NODE, user, and password with the correct values.***

Restart the node to take the changes:

```
$ systemctl restart postgresql-14
```

Then, you can run this in your Primary node to see the replication nodes:

```
$ SELECT pid,usename,application_name,state,sync_state FROM pg_stat_replication;

  pid  |     usename      | application_name |   state   | sync_state
-------+------------------+------------------+-----------+------------
 10951 | replication_user | pgsql_0_node_1   | streaming | async
 10952 | replication_user | pgsql_0_node_0   | streaming | sync
(2 rows)
```